# Getting NHibernate to report mapping problems

Tags: nhibernate

So I've been doing some work with NHibernate, and while what I have seen is mostly great, one thing is a little frustrating. If I try to query for some objects and there is a mapping problem in or with the hbm file, often there is no indication that there is a mapping problem, it just returns no results.

A simple example is if I forget to set the hbm file as an embedded resource, and then do a `session.Query<Variable>().ToList()`, there is no indication that there is no mapping for Variable, it just returns an empty list.

Is there any way to tell NHibernate to throw an exception or otherwise indicate that there is a problem with the mapping(s) in situations like this?

This does result in an exception:

```
_session.Get<Variable>(1)
```

But these do not:

```
_session.Query<Variable>().Where(e => e.VariableId == 1).ToList()

_session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Variable)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("VariableId",1)).List<Variable>();
```

Hopefully it's something that I'm doing wrong, or something that can be configured, otherwise it will probably be a deal-breaker for using NHibernate. I can catch these things in my own unit tests relatively easy, but I can just see this becoming a festival of bugs when other developers start touching it.

Comment: I am surprised it doesn't throw an exception. Does it also fail silently if you use QueryOver?

Comment: Yes, I just tried QueryOver and it has the same behavior.

Comment: I'm downloading the source code to take a look now. The glory of Open Source.

Comment: Something tells me that there is something not right in your project. By default NHibernate throws a MappingException with a "No persister for: entity" message. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436072/nhibernate-mappingexception-no-persister)

Comment: Interestingly _session.Get<Variable>(1) does throw an exception, but _session.Query<Variable>().Where(e => e.VariableId == 1).ToList() does not. I think the difference may be that .Get really depends on there being an id mapping.

Comment: After trying Get I thought maybe it was just the IQueryable interface, which I will probably not be using in production code, but it looks like the ICriteria interface does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of digging through the code, I suspect you are right. Unmapped classes don't throw an exception on a List.

https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionImpl.cs#L1869

```
            string[] implementors = Factory.GetImplementors(criteria.EntityOrClassName);
            int size = implementors.Length;

            CriteriaLoader[] loaders = new CriteriaLoader[size];
            ISet<string> spaces = new HashSet<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                loaders[i] = new CriteriaLoader(
                    GetOuterJoinLoadable(implementors[i]),
                    Factory,
                    criteria,
                    implementors[i],
                    enabledFilters
                    );

                spaces.UnionWith(loaders[i].QuerySpaces);
            }
```

Note how if there are no implementors that are returned by Factory.GetImplementors, no error is generated, but nothing is done. Hence why you are seeing an empty list come back.

If we look at [SessionFactoryImpl.GetImplementors](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionFactoryImpl.cs#L625) we see that at no point is an exception thrown if no implementor is found. Just an empty array of implementors is returned.

So potentially there needs to be a check that if no implementors are returned by Factory.GetImplementors, a MappingException needs to be thrown.

Comment: Yeah, it does appear that way. It's a shame. I hear so many good things about NHibernate, and I really like how easy it is to map POCOs, but the fact that something so simple and fundamental as this does not seem to be addressed is probably going to scare me away. The last thing I need is to find out 4 or 5 months down the road that our application has not been working correctly because one of the developers fiddled with a database mapping and the ORM just pretended there was an empty table. Exploring EF now...

Comment: Yeah that is concerning and now that EF is open source it does make it a viable alternative

Comment: Yep. The EF mapping files are a bit more complex, and thus will be more work to auto-generate when I get to that point, but it looks like it won't be too bad.

Comment: So I posted this question on the NHibernate users forum and never did get any response. Between this issue and no response on their forum, it just doesn't seem like something I want to trust with a critical application. Entity Framework seems to do everything I need, and while Microsoft can be spotty, at least I know I can get a support response from them when needed.